# Custom type in generic function implementation

Tags: typescript

I struggle on this problem (I know that I can rewrite in different way I just want only to understand if it's possible) to pass into a generic type of implementation for an interface a custom type, or I can only pass a native TS type (string, number, etc.):

```
type coordinates = {
  x: string;
  y: string;
};

interface polygon {
  convert<T>(cord: T): string;
}

class triangle implements polygon {
  public cord: coordinates;
  constructor(cord: coordinates) {
    this.cord = cord;
  }
  convert(cord: coordinates): string {
    return "the coordinates is x:" + cord.x + " y:" + cord.y;
  }
}
```

I use TypeScript 4.9.5.
The editor give me this error in the implementation of convert:

The property 'convert' in type 'triangle' is not assignable to the same property in base type `polygon`.
Type `(cord: coordinates) => string` is not assignable to type `<T>(cord: T) => string`.
Types of parameters 'cord' and 'cord' are incompatible.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'coordinates'.

Comment: Yes, you can use _any_ type as the generic type argument.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sometimes it depends on the context so not always. `class Example<T extends this>` throws an error.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn they have to be compatible with any constraints, yes, but you're certainly _not_ limited to only built-in types.

Comment: If you're not asking about the error in your code then the error is distracting.  Callers can call `convert` with any type argument they want; this is clearly not your intent.  It isn't `Polygon.convert` that should be generic, but `Polygon` itself, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjDx8m).  So I'm not sure how to proceed here? What exactly is your question?

Comment: ah ok sorry because my editor give me and error in the implementation of convert function.
Property 'convert' in type 'triangle' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'polygon'.
  Type '(cord: coordinates) => string' is not assignable to type '<T>(cord: T) => string'.
    Types of parameters 'cord' and 'cord' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'coordinates'.

Comment: So are you asking "why is this error happening"? If so it's because `convert` needs to accept any argument the *caller* wants, not the *implementer*.  The error is a good error and your code is incorrect.  Or are you asking "how do I fix this"?  Then you need to make the *class* generic, not the *method*.  The problem and solution are shown [in tihs playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgD4BN) (also, spelling & naming conventions have been fixed, pls note).  Should I write that up as an answer? Or did I fail to address something about the question?

Comment: yes, sorry I see now my error thanks for your help, sorry my first time that I post on stack overflow net time i be more precise on the explanation

Answer (score 2):

The following type

```
interface Polygon {
  convert<T>(coord: T): string;
}
```

is a non-[generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types) type, with a generic `convert` method.  For generic methods (and generic functions in general), the *caller* specifies the type argument.  So a `Polygon` would need to allow callers to call `convert()` with any `T` type argument they like:

```
function foo(p: Polygon) {
  p.convert(123); // okay
  // (method) Polygon.convert<number>(coord: number): string
  p.convert(new Date()); // okay
  // (method) Polygon.convert<Date>(coord: Date): string
}
```

That means the *implementer* of an instance of `Polygon` is *not* allowed to make a restricting assumption on what `T` will be specified as.  They need to support all possible `T` types.  So the following is invalid:

```
class Triangle implements Polygon {
  public coord: Coordinates;
  constructor(coord: Coordinates) {
    this.coord = coord;
  }
  convert(coord: Coordinates): string { // error!
    return "the coordinates is x:" +
      coord.x.toUpperCase() + " y:" + coord.y;
  }
}
```

The `Triangle` class does not properly implement `Polygon`.  A `Triangle`'s `convert()` method requires a `Coordinates` argument, but the implementer of `Polygon` does not get to make that choice.

---

I very much doubt that you want a `Polygon` to accept any possible input to `convert`.  So you will probably be happier changing to this version:

```
interface Polygon<T> {
  convert(coord: T): string;
}
```

That is a *generic* type with a *non-generic* method.  There is no more type that's `Polygon` by itself; instead the type is `Polygon<T>` and you need to specify the  type argument `T` when you mention that type.  For example a `Polygon<number>` has a `{convert(coord: number): string}` method.  And a `Polygon<Coordinates>` has a `{convert(coord: Coordinates): string}` method.  So in order to implement the interface, the implementer needs to choose the `T` type argument, and then the callers of `convert()` have no choice but to call it with the argument the implementer chose.

And now we can see that a `Triangle` is indeed a valid `Polygon<Coordinates>`:

```
class Triangle implements Polygon<Coordinates> {
  public coord: Coordinates;
  constructor(coord: Coordinates) {
    this.coord = coord;
  }
  convert(coord: Coordinates): string {
    return "the coordinates is x:" +
      coord.x.toUpperCase() + " y:" + coord.y;
  }
}
```

And if you are given a `Polygon<Coordinates>` then you can't call `convert()` with arbitrary arguments anymore:

```
function foo(p: Polygon<Coordinates>) {
  p.convert(123); // error!
  p.convert(new Date()); // error!
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEATJBvAUEpALgJ4zIDCA9hQE7oCWoB0SAvNnvkgB4BcSUBagwDmAbg74ifAUOBiOAX3EcGTagDMEyAAoUANkWEVg7TknjGAbhGoEAPABUAfAAoLNdHwcBKaYJHi+Ao4HPB6IFBQSA5CIHJ6yHRgMAmQwARRugZGJrhmMACuAEZ6dPDmVLR8lB4MIExQgZwWwDIF8AQ0bpWeSDW0dQ3epmaEABZ0UAB07rSsFR5NQRIVwNa23R7VPYPQvvz+cthIAPQnSDbUNACEK-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-Bgi97keZ43g+L4QK4mcol4bEwQoiEoVheEbCRKA3RBDE60BTzcXxFZNNfTMyQpKkszpBlWOMdjLIaJwFLMNMjL48MCP5IURQ7bteyif4hGEMYCHXB4ACsIA6XckGACh7QCo8CBPM8EtGCTr1ve9H28AKU0zWlc3nAtFxLMtXgrKta3rV5G2bQk209LseyU3Komqx0xwgCcpwgHAFCAA)